# Read and write JSON values with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

for storing api key in json i made a python program with sof help which takes input from user. the following code works fine and writes to json file

```
import json
k = {}
k['key']='api_key='+ input("enter key")
with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(k, outfile, indent=4)
print("success")
```

output:(written to file)

```
{
"key": "api_key=fdcjlklhkkgjyf8769ljlihhfhdasfdsagf"
}
```

but while reading with the following code it outputs vertically

```
import json 

f = open('sample.json',) 
data = json.load(f) 
for i in data['key']: 
    print(i) 
f.close()
```

output:

```
a
p
i
_
k
e
y
=
f
d
c
j
l
k
l
h
k
k
g
j
y
f
8
7
6
9
l
j
l
i
h
h
f
h
d
a
s
f
d
s
a
g
f
```

how can i get a normal output. i think there are two ways by writing in nested or reading without for loop.

Comment: You're iterating over the string with `for i in data['key']`. You probably just want `print(data['key'])`.

Comment: `data['key']` is a string, so just print it directly without looping.

Comment: `data[key]` itself points to the string. You are just iterating over the `data[key]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop over the object `data['key']` but this object is a `string` in your JSON file. So the `for` loop will print each character of the string. Check [this](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-iterate-over-the-characters-in-string/) for more information.
You have to remove the loop and access the key directly:

```
import json 

f = open('Sample.json',) 
data = json.load(f) 
print(data["key"]) 
f.close()
```

Or you change your member `key` in your JSON into an array:

```
{
    "key": [
        "fdcjlklhkkgjyf8769ljlihhfhdasfdsagf"
        ]
}
```

Both will output the key:

```
$ python Test.py
fdcjlklhkkgjyf8769ljlihhfhdasfdsagf
```

So the complete code will look like this (as an example for two keys):

```
import json

k = {}
Keys = list()

for i in range(2):
    Keys.append(input("enter key: "))

k['key'] = Keys

with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(k, outfile, indent=4)
print("success")
```

This results in:

```
{
    "key": [
        "a",
        "c"
    ]
}
```

And can be read:

```
import json 

f = open('Sample.json') 
data = json.load(f)
for Key in data["key"]:
    print(Key) 
f.close()

$ python Test.py
a
c
```

Comment: Thanks and  yes as i said there are two by removing loop or by writing in nested way (array) in first place. but  i could't think slowly for a bit so put it on here. also can you please update your answer with writing as an array from user input this would make perfect answer to the question

Answer (score 2):

```
import json 

f = open('sample.json',) 
data = json.load(f) 
print(data['key'])
f.close()
```

data['key'] itself is a string. So when you loop over it, each time it iterates through each character.

```
Eg:

a='Nandu'
for i in a:
 print(i)

Output:
N
a
n
d
u
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this

```
import json
k = {}
k['main']='api_key='+ input("enter key: ")
with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(k, outfile, indent=4)
print("successfully written")

f = open('sample.json',) 
data = json.load(f) 
print(data['main'][8:])
f.close()
```

you will get

[image: output]